# ExpressionEngine: Multiple channels issue with custom URL's

Tags: expressionengine

On this page:
http://build.jhousemedia3.com/pleasanton/shop/district-profile/stoneridge-shopping-center/

The URL is formatted like so
http://build.jhousemedia3.com/pleasanton/[channel]/[template]/[query parameter]

I'm running an exp:channel:entries query using the last segment of the URL  (segment_4)

What's happening is that when I run it from this URL I can't pull in data from any other channel except the specific shopping districts channel.  If I were to change that last segment to /?id=28 (or something similar) I can pull data from multiple channels.

Any ideas?

Code for pulling the profile of a shopping district based on the URL:

```
{exp:channel:entries url_title="{segment_4}" limit="1" channel="shopping_districts"}
    <h2 class="upper"><span class="greenlight">{title}</span></h2>
    {if center_website}
        <div class="greyroundbox right"><a href="{center_website}" class="external-link" target='_blank'>Visit the Website</a></div>
    {/if}
    <p>{shopping_center_description}</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Code for pulling in any business data

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="businesses"}
    <li class="{switch='first|'}">
        <p>
        <a href="{path='pages/business-profile'}" class="main-title">{business_name}</a>
        <a href="{path='pages/shopping-category'}" class="green-title">{categories_shopping}</a><br />
        {if phone}
            <strong>Phone</strong>: {phone}<br />
        {/if}
        <strong>Address</strong>: {address_1}<br />
        {if address_2}
            {address_2}<br />
        {/if}
        {city}, {state}, {zip}<br />
        {if website}
            <a href="{website}" class="grey"><em>{website}</em></a>
        {/if}
        </p>
    </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Sounds like a very specific template setup. Posting the code that lives in the `district-profile` template would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe obvious, but have you added dynamic="no" to your other loop?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="businesses" dynamic="no"}
```